# using .env with react-script start

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying everything, but I can't succeed.
I need to use .env file during development, with react-scripts start

I have been following this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/
and I keep getting process is not defined.

I tried countless solutions found here, but no luck.
I read that it injects the variables during build, so there is no way at all to use it during development?

Last thing I have tried is env-cmd

My script looks like this:

```
        "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start",
```

still it says process is undefined.
Any help is appreciated
thanks

Comment: can you attach one of your env variable key and value?

Comment: REACT_APP_ACCOUNT_SID=Axxxxxxxxxxxx

I tried with 
var accountSid=process.env.REACT_APP_ACCOUNT_SID
and
var accountSid=process.env.ACCOUNT_SID
no luck

Comment: appConfig.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at appConfig.js:4

Answer (score 1):

you have to create an .env file at the root of the project

**don't forget to add REACT_APP at the beginning of the variable**.

#### .env

REACT_APP_FOO=foo

#### App.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{process.env.REACT_APP_FOO}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can see this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-cache-xtjci?file=/src/App.js:24-153)

Comment: ok it works now in index.js that is inside src..
I have another js that is in public/assets and it doesn't work there..

Comment: @jsabina look the sandbox i create a file in public/assets

Answer (score 0):

try this

in `.env` file :

```
REACT_APP_DEVELOP_URL=https://test.example.com
REACT_APP_PROD_URL=https://api.example.com
```

in `package.json` file

```
  `"start-dev": "set REACT_APP_IP_MODE=development&& npm run dev",`
  `"start-prod": "set REACT_APP_IP_MODE=production&& npm run dev"`
```

and usage in project :

```
let baseURL;
const env = process.env;

switch (env.REACT_APP_IP_MODE) {
case "development":
  baseURL = env.REACT_APP_DEVELOP_URL;
  break;
case "production":
  baseURL = env.REACT_APP_PROD_URL;
  break;
default:
  baseURL = env.REACT_APP_DEVELOP_URL;
  break;
}
```